# Check if any value ( multiple columns) of one data frame exists in any values (multiple columns) of another data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames with similar data in different formats

df1:

```
Nodo      X          Y          Z
CTB3901   CTBX3901   CTBY3901   CTBZ3901
MTR5331   MTRX5331   MTRY5331   MTRZ5331
ADC3451   ADCX3451   ADCY3451   ADCZ3451
```

df2:

```
Site_x     Site_y
CTBX3901E  CTBX3901
CTB3901    CTB3901E
CTBZ3901E  CTBZ3901
CTBY3901E  CTB3901
MADX6379E  MADX6379
```

I want to check if any entries from `df2['Site_x', 'Site_y']` is in any of  the columns `df1['Nodo','X','Y','Z']`. The data need not be in the same row in both frames.

The final output after the check shud be as below

```
Site_x     Site_y   Checked
CTBX3901E  CTBX3901  True
CTB3901    CTB3901E  True
CTBZ3901E  CTBZ3901  True
CTBY3901E  CTB3901   True
MADX6379E  MADX6379  False
```

Pardon me for the clumsy dataset. In desperation of getting this part right, I had to paste the same data I was working with.

I've tried isin method with the below syntax but the output has False in the entire 'Checked' column.

```
df2['Checked'] = df2[['Site_x','Site_y']].isin(df1[['Nodo','X','Y','Z']]).any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close:

```
df2['checked'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.isin(df1.stack())).any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Quang. This helped me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using [`np.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with `.isin()`:

```
df2['Checked']=df2.isin(df1.values.ravel()).any(axis=1)
print(df2)
```

---

```
      Site_x    Site_y  Checked
0  CTBX3901E  CTBX3901     True
1    CTB3901  CTB3901E     True
2  CTBZ3901E  CTBZ3901     True
3  CTBY3901E   CTB3901     True
4  MADX6379E  MADX6379    False
```

Comment: Of course I would've used `assign` (-: `df2.assign(Checked=df2.isin(np.ravel(df1)).any(1))`

Comment: This helped me in getting the desired output. But if I have to work around only using pandas, then @Quang Hoang 's way suites better. Thank you :)

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you :) , I do use `assign()` a lot, this time didn't. Do you know if `assign()` performs better?

Comment: @vvk24 Sure. whatever suits you more :). I use numpy wherever I can(and whatever little I know of numpy) for performance reasons.

Comment: @vvk24 why must you only uses Pandas?  When you import Pandas, you get Numpy along with it.  It's under `pandas.np`.  So what is the scenario that dictates that you must avoid using Numpy functions?

Answer (score 1):

Another method using also the `np.ravel()` same as [anky_91's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56873762/9081267) answer but then using [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) which can be more general, but less easily expandable when having more columns:

```
df2['Checked'] = df2['Site_x'].str.cat(df2['Site_y']).str.contains('|'.join(df1.values.ravel()))
```

```
      Site_x    Site_y  Checked
0  CTBX3901E  CTBX3901     True
1    CTB3901  CTB3901E     True
2  CTBZ3901E  CTBZ3901     True
3  CTBY3901E   CTB3901     True
4  MADX6379E  MADX6379    False
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Fun with Numpy

Or as I call it, Funpy

```
a = df2.to_numpy()[..., None, None]
b = df1.to_numpy()[None, None, ...]
df2.assign(Checked=(a == b).any(axis=(1, 2, 3)))

      Site_x    Site_y  Checked
0  CTBX3901E  CTBX3901     True
1    CTB3901  CTB3901E     True
2  CTBZ3901E  CTBZ3901     True
3  CTBY3901E   CTB3901     True
4  MADX6379E  MADX6379    False
```

Comment: four dimensions (-:

Comment: i am pulling the last piece of hair left :P